# java vs C++ for natural language processing

Tags: java, c++, nlp

Could you please let me know which one is better to learn amongst Java and C++ for natural language processing with respect to library,support etc.

Best, Thetna

Answer (score 4):

It looks like [you have a number of options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_natural_language_processing_toolkits) with either language.

The solution is far more than the language it is implemented in.  Either language should provide sufficient power.

Between Java and C++, in general, I would choose Java.  Java did come a bit after C++ and it does address a few concerns that the C++ community had (note the past tense).  That said, depending on what you are integrating with, whether you view automatic garbage collection as a benefit or a detriment, and which language you or your team is more intimate with, you might easily select either one.

Perhaps to better answer your question, you should consider [the criteria for selecting a good programming language.](http://archive.adaic.com/docs/reports/lawlis/content.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Either language is technically capable of doing rich NLP.  Anecdotally, it seems that the most popular NLP libraries, such as Stanford's and LingPipe, are both in Java, however.

Also, if you are planning on developing a web application, Java is very well suited for that to.

That said, C++ is equally capable as java, and there do exist established NLP libraries there as well.